# Add a observation (remark) after a sitting of training

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have in fact 3 forms:

The first is `students` with 2 fields `(name, firstname)`.

The second is `trainings` with 2 fields `(date_sitting`, fk_student)`.

[image]

The next is the form `observations` with 3 fields `(title, description, fk_student)`.

[image]

My problem is that I can add **2 dates sittings** for **1 observation** for the same date.

Is it it's possible to make a blocking for this genre of case?

Here is an idea of my code so far:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required|string|max:30',
                'description' => 'required|string|max:80',
                'fk_student' => 'required'

        ]);

        $exists = Observation::where('title', $request->get('title'))->where('description', $request->get('description'))->where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->count();

        if (!$exists){

        $sittings = Training::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();


        if(!isset($sittings)){ // No payment = block creation and return error msg.
            return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                    ->with('error', 'No sitting, no observation for you!');
        }
        else{
            Observation::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                    ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
            }
        }

        if(isset($exists)){
            return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                    ->with('error', 'Duplicate ! ');
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you've got the right code to see if there is an **Observation** already.  Now you just need to check if there is a **Sitting** for this student on the same day as the **Observation**.  So:

```
if (!$exists){

    $sitting = Training::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
                ->where('date_sitting', , '=', **SOME formatted DATE**)->first();


    if(isset($sitting)){ // If we have a match to student on the requested date, no good, return.
        return redirect()->route('observations.index')
                ->with('error', 'You already have a sitting for this date!');
}
```

The problem is that when you say:

> My problem is that I can add 2 dates sittings for 1 observation for the same date.

I don't know what date is the 'same date'.  Same date as what the user is sending through the form to request a **Sitting**?  Or a set date on the **Observation**?  IE I think you need to decide what date you are comparing to - there is no incoming date in your code above.  You need a date to compare to (probably from a user form fed into the `$request` object injected in the `store()` method) to make the code above work.

Comment: In fact, the user can enter a date_sitting for a observation only. For example: for the date sitting (07-11-2019), there is one observation only. In my first message on the topic; the user can create several observation (see screenshot 2) for one date_sitting . I wil wish to control this. 1 observation = 1 training. I don't know if you have understand my question now?

Comment: Yes, the problem, however, is that you don't have a field on the Observation to control 1 Observation = 1 Training.  There is no `date_sitting` on the Observation.  If there was, you could compare by dates.  Without it, you have to use the method in my answer, *which will work*, but is more complex.  You can also solve this by adding a FK to Observation for `training_id`.  Then, write a bit more code to compare if a specific training is already assigned.  Suggest take my code above, or add the date_sitting in addition to the fk_student on the Observation for simple 1 to 1 comparison & control.

Comment: I now test your first code but I have an error message which is => `syntax error, unexpected '**' (T_POW)`. Is it a problem of version PHP ??

Comment: Oh shoot, no, that's not code.  That was a note to remind you to add in the date that the sitting was requested for.  I didn't see where you were pulling that in your `store()` method code (from the form where the user requests the date).  So, that area is where you need to add in the date the user has requested (in correct format to match `date_sitting`).  If it doesn't matter which date was requested (if ANY student with a sitting already made is ineligible for making an Observation), you can remove that part of the code to compare dates.